# GeoLocation track & insert into mysqlDatabse

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

**I want to track user location and save into database**
I'm using geolocation script to track user location data into mysql database while loading the page. But the geolocation data is not inserted into database. Here is the codes

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$data1=$_POST['location'];
mysqli_query($con,"insert into table(raw) values('$data1')");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="location" id="demo" type="hidden" /></form>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

  var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/@"+latlon;
 x.innerHTML = url;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it in a wrong way. you see the code execution sequence, body will load prior to the form, and `<form> </form>` is not posting anything back php script, since, only field, i,e, is hidden does not contain any value. 
To achieve this you need to do the following in your code:

```
<pre><form><input type="hidden" id="demo" name="location" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
 elem.value = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
</script></form>
```